# Android Device not found by ADB tool

Tags: android, cordova

I want to deploy android app on device. But when run 'cordova run android --device' throws error as,

`ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.
Error: /home/inkilab/golang/src/github.com/okpatil4u/android/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)`

When I enlist adb devices output is as

`List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device`

I have enabled USB debugging on my android device. So, what is the problem now?

Comment: Are you supposed to deploy it on a virtual or physical device ?

Comment: On a physical device @Alex

Comment: For more relevance, I will post few proposition here to make your device detected : You should first change your post title, in something like "Android Device not found by ADB tool", then try to check if all your USB drivers are correctly installed.  Go in your computer properties and in your components manager, and check if the Android Phone is correctly recognized with no warning or errors.

Comment: Edited my question, and there are no errrors or warning while connecting my phone.

Comment: even I have switched MTP mode to PTP mode, as mentioned in other posts but this is also not working. My phone is xiomi mi4. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have connected only emulator. 
please connect or disconnect the device and you should confirm security question. 
Check usb cable.

Comment: I have connected my device with usb. But it doesn't show in adb devices list

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your device identifier in your command line like this :

```
cordova run android --device=emulator-5554
```

See, in your error trace, it try to install apk on the 'device :' <- void identifier

Comment: I want to run it on my external android device, not on emulator.

Comment: Ok, your device is rooted or not ?

Comment: device is rooted means?

Comment: A rooted device is a device which was given the Root permissions, so basically you can do any command or actions on it, with elevated privileges. I had a rooted android device once (with also custom recovery), and I couldn't make it recognizable by the adb tool.

Comment: and how to check this?

Comment: If you didn't do anything to your phone, it's not rooted by default, so I am quite sure it's not the issue here